# User profile photo disappears from side menu on iOS app when there is no network

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, profile-picture

iOS app version 1.6.3

When the side menu is called, the icon of the user is constantly loaded, I would make a check before uploading the user's picture permanently, in the second, when the internet is turned off, the picture disappears altogether, I would use the "placeholder" Put the last uploaded picture of the user and if there is no Internet, it would display the last downloaded one.

before

[image]

after with Airplane mode

[image]

Comment: No-repro, putting the device in airplane mode and opening the side menu shows my profile photo correctly. Is there some cache expiration time you suggest waiting?

Comment: @grgarside I add screenshots in my questions.

Comment: Yup that’s what I tried, no-repro unfortunately.

Comment: Same behavior here @ИсмаилХасбулатов